# Extra queries in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There's a JPA entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Release {

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id")
    
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "original_project_id")
    private Project originalProject;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "release")
    private List<ProjectRelease> releaseProjects;
    
        public String getArticleNumber() {
        return CommonUtil.getArticleNumberForUpc(code);
    }
    
}
```

Inside a look, I'm executing this piece of code;

```
    Release release = releases.stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getArticleNumber().equals(articleNumber))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

Every time the code above is executed, an extra DB query is issued for the originalProject and another one for the list of projects associated to each release which I think does not make any sense because the filter method on the stream is not accessing or reading any of these fields.

I re wrote the Spring Data JPA query to join fetch the project, now the query to retrieve the project is not being issued, however there's still an extra query for the list of projects which is being issued.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you are probably accessing the collection some where, if you are using Lombok with `@Data` don't, that is a bad thing to use for entities. Also lazy loading for single elements (the *ToOne mappings) only work with bytecode enhancements, without it it won't work.